# Turtle moving from its current location to selected destination without moving straight from one node to another

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make a turtle to move from its current node location to a node destination without having it to jump from one node to another, but instead move progressively from one node to another. I looked at Move Towards Target Example and Link-Walking Turtles Example models and tried to combine these in the code below which seems to make the turtle move from one node to another progressively, but only in a random manner.

```
to walk
  let distance-from-current-location distance current-location
  ifelse 0.5 < distance from-current-location [
    fd 0.5 ]
  [
    let new-location one-of [ link-neighbors ] of current-location
    face new-location
    set current-location new-location
  ]
end
```

What I would like is the turtle to walk progressively between nodes until it reaches its destination. For example, I tried the code below but the turtle ends up walking off the links.

```
to walk
  if current-location != destination [
    let next-node item 1 [ nw:turtles-on-path-to [ destination ] of myself ] of current-location
    set current-location next-node
    ifelse distance current-location < 0.5 [
      move-to current-location ]
    [
      face current-location
      fd 0.5
    ]
end
```

How could I make the turtle move between the nodes of its selected path from current location to destination without moving straight from one node to another? For example, instead of jumping from node 1 to node 2 to node 3 ... to node n, I would like the turtle to forward 0.5 from node 1 to node 2 ... until it reaches the destination node.

Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't look obviously incorrect. When you say that it walked off the links, do you mean that the direction wasn't quite right, or that it kept on moving too far in the correct direction, or something else?

Comment: Instead of forwarding 0.5 until it reaches the next node, the turtle moves 0.5 in the direction of next node only once and then keeps moving 0.5 in a different direction. Some of the nodes are really close to one another so it could be that the turtle moves too far passing by its next node without reaching it. For example, when the turtle is at 0.5 distance from next node then it is supposed to move to it straight away. Could it be that the turtle advances too much so it is never 0.5 away from its next node hence not moving to it? How could I fix this?

Comment: with that better explanation, i can see a logic error. You set the current location to the next node, then the next time it loops, I think it will set to the next node in the path and then the next loop to the next node because the `let next-node...` line is being updated as the current-location is being updated.

Comment: All sorted now. Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `current-location` is being updated to the next node *before* the turtle actually reaches it. Try this:

```
to walk
  if current-location != destination [
    ifelse distance current-location < 0.5 [
      move-to current-location
      let next-node item 1 [ nw:turtles-on-path-to [ destination ] of myself ] of current-location
      set current-location next-node
    ] [
      face current-location
      fd 0.5
    ]
end
```

Thus, `current-location` is only changed when the turtle actually reaches it. Though, that makes me think that "`current-location`" is the wrong name for it. Also, with this code, the turtle will stop at the node *before* the final node. So consider making `next-node` a turtle variable. Then try this code:

```
to walk
  if current-location != destination [
    ifelse distance next-node < 0.5 [
      ;; Close enough to the next node; make it my current location
      ;; and target the next node on the list.
      set current-location next-node
      move-to current-location
      set next-node item 1 [ nw:turtles-on-path-to [ destination ] of myself ] of current-location
    ] [
      ;; Not there yet; keep walking towards the next node.
      face next-node
      fd 0.5
    ]
end
```